# UIWebView must get localStorage item and store it in the app natively / retrive it natively

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, local-storage

I have the first part figured out...

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*) myTapView {
     NSString *jsString = @"localStorage.getItem('username');";
     NSString *someKeyValue = [tapView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

     // This is where I would start storing it so I can retrieve it later
}
```

So here is my issue, I need to store the value I just got from localStorage so I can use it again. Problem is I don't know where to start. This code is inside my ViewController for the WebView, so I need to be able to use it in other areas in the ViewController.m file.

What is the best method for storing the info? I would also want the above code to be able to update the value, as it won't always be the same username (people can switch accounts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to store data on iOS, but it depends on what kind of value you want to store. If it's just a plain string or other "light" data, the best approach is to save it to `NSUserDefaults`. If it's an image or video, you may want to consider archiving it using `NSKeyedArchiver`. Otherwise, if you want to build a complicated data model, use Core Data.

Here's a good [post on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) that describe in detail pros and cons of each approach.

According to your code, you want to store a string. I'd go with `NSUserDefaults` in this case.

Comment: This appears to work (using the NSUserDefaults snippet from NSHipster), but it only works once, if the app tries to pull the info again and set the key again, it shows up as nothing. :\

Comment: nevermind, the NSHipster idea is working the best for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSUserDefaults to store UIWebView local storage value as follows

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*) myTapView {
        NSString *jsString = @"localStorage.getItem('username');";
        NSString *someKeyValue = [myTapView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

         // Store your Username in iPhone persistence variable and use it later in the application
        NSUserDefaults *userdefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userdefault setObject:someKeyValue forKey:@"username"];
        [userdefault synchronize];

        //use of User default
        NSLog(@"User name %@",[userdefault valueForKey:@"username"]);
    }
```

Comment: How can I use synchronize without putting it inside [userdefault syncrhonize]; ? Let us say I am using NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:someKeyValue];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"username"];

Comment: you can directly write [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] syncrhonize];